# Is react-query's query.state.dataUpdateCount mutable?

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm working on live polling for a list of logs, using `react-query`'s [`useInfiniteQuery`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useInfiniteQuery).

We have a button that turns live polling on and off manually. We want to add an auto-off feature that will make it stop refetching after running for `maxRefetches` times. This will help us save resources in case someone leaves a poll running when they are no longer viewing it.

We also want to allow them to turn live polling back on, in case their code is still producing logs and they are still actively viewing them after they hit `maxRefetches`. Setting `query.state.dataUpdateCount` to 0 seems like a straightforward way to let them run up to `maxRefetches` again.

So, inside `useInfiniteQuery()`, we have the `refetchInterval` option:

```
refetchInterval: (_data, query) => {
    if (query.state.dataUpdateCount >= maxRefetches) {
        // the following line sets refetchInterval to false through a side effect
        setLivePolling(false);            
        query.state.dataUpdateCount = 0;
    }
    return refetchInterval;
},
```

This works and doesn't throw any errors, but I'm curious if it's OK to manually reset `query.state.dataUpdateCount` inside `refetchInterval` like this - I couldn't find an answer in the docs or on Stack Overflow. Does anyone know if this would have any consequences or break some convention I'm not aware of? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is react-query's query.state.dataUpdateCount mutable?

No. If you want state you can reset, you'd need to manage this on your end.